# Luigi: Incorrect Dependency Graph

Tags: python, etl, luigi

So I installed Luigi and started playing with it by following this [tut](https://bionics.it/posts/luigi-tutorial). All worked well but I am not able to see the dependency graph properly.

I ran the command: `python luigitutorial.py --scheduler-host localhost NameSubstituter --name Jerry`

The screens are given below. AS you can see it shows as an isolated task instead of a dependent task.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because this task has no dependency.
Click on the NameSubstituter and you will see the dependency

Comment: @NickRyan For some reason, the image was not uploaded. I have updated the question.

Comment: I found the reason. *Hide Done* was enabled. I disabled and it worked as it should. Should I remove the Question?

Comment: In this case, disable "Hide done". This option is useful if you have many dependent tasks and you need to see only tasks which are not done yet